# Firebase - how to set custom claim from the console

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-console

In my application I use firebase authentication and Google account as credentials provider. I would like to assign roles to users. In order to do it I would like to add custom claims to the authentication token a user gets during login. And here is my problem because I don't know how to add claims to existing user from the firebase console.

Comment: In addition to Frank's answer, you may be interested by this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-an-admin-module-for-managing-users-access-and-roles-34a94cf31a6e) which details how to build a simple web interface to create users and assign them specific Custom Claims *(disclaimer, I'm the author)*.

Comment: In addition to @RenaudTarnec 's comment, you may be interested in this experimental extension from firebase: "firestore auth claims", which triggers a function in the back end any time you write a document in firestore and simply copy-pasts the content of the doc to the user's claim. If you simply do nothing in your rules to authorize reads or writes in that collection, you can only update its docs from your console or your back end. Here is the logic behind that extension: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/experimental-extensions/blob/next/firestore-auth-claims/functions/src/index.ts

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There is currently no way to set custom claims for a user in the Firebase console. If you think this would be a useful addition, [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) for it.

In the meantime the easiest way to add a custom claim is to do so from the a terminal window/command prompt using a small Node.js script like this:

```
admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, {admin: true})
```

A alternative is to use this experimental (but working) [Extension that synchronizes custom claims between Firestore documents and Authentication](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/experimental-extensions/tree/next/firestore-auth-claims).

Also see:

- [How to create Firebase Authentication claims?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47495678/how-to-create-firebase-authentication-claims/47497957#47497957)