# how to access Firestore collections for doctors and users I don't know he is user or doctor

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to store doctors and users two different collections on the firestore I have created different collections one for users and one for doctors in registration activity. Now the problem is when someone wants to log in I don't know he is a user or doctor I need to call the collection in the main activity I want to display all the details of user or doctor how can i identify which collection i need to call
for example, when doctors want to log in I only know his email  id and I want to show all the details of him
in main activity  i dont know which collection i need to call because i don't know he is a doctor or a user

I have created two collections because I wanna show all the doctors list to the user
and users list to doctors

my app details
My first activity is login activity, if someone is new, they can register
now let's start with Register activity
[this is my Register activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwdDS.jpg)

```
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword( binding.etEmail.text.toString().trim { it <= ' ' }, binding.etPassword.text.toString().trim { it <= ' ' })
                .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
       if (task.isSuccessful) {

                        val firebaseUser: FirebaseUser = task.result!!.user!!

                        val user = User(
                              firebaseUser.uid,
                          binding.etFirstName.text.toString().trim{it<=' '},
                          binding.etLastName.text.toString().trim{it<=' '},
                          binding.etEmail.text.toString().trim { it <= ' ' },
                            )

                        if (binding.rbUser.isChecked){
                          
         // registerUser method create a  user collection on firebase 
                            FirestoreClass().registerUser(this,user)
                        }else{
           //  // registerDoctors method create a doctor collection on firebase 
                            FirestoreClass().registerDoctors(this, user)
                           
                        }


                    } else {
                      
                        showErrorSnackBar(task.exception!!.message.toString(), true)

                    }

                }
```

I think i don't need to put   FirestoreClass().registerUser(this,user) and  FirestoreClass().registerDoctors(this, user) methods code all work fine now i have two collection

[This is my  firestore collections sreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJZbq.png)

now someone wants to login I don't know he/she is a doctor or user

[This is my login activity layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5nm0.jpg)

```
         // this is my login activity
        val email = binding.etEmail.text.toString().trim{it <= ' '}
        val password = binding.etPassword.text.toString().trim{it <= ' '}

        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
                .addOnCompleteListener {
                    task ->

                 if(task.isSuccessful){
                 
// Now how can I identify This is A doctor or A user what should I put in if blocks please tell 
                if (  )
                    FirestoreClass().getDoctorDtails(this@LoginActivity)
                  else{
                    FirestoreClass().getUserDetails(this@LoginActivity)

                }
                    }else{

                     //   hideProgressDialog()
                        showErrorSnackBar(task.exception!!.message.toString(), true)

                    }
```

if your have any solution for this please tell me how can i know he/she is a doctor and i user

Comment: You can ask from a user that whether he wants to log in as doctor or as a user. Or the second way is to have some alteration in your database...... like make only one collection and add a extra property like isDoctor = true  , so in this way you will be able to search in you all users and also you will get to know that whether he is a doctor or a user.Feel free to ask if somethingi is unclear.

Comment: I think [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55655249/how-we-can-check-from-firestore-that-email-belongs-to-which-collection/55655868#55655868) might help, right?

Comment: if I ask are you a doctor or a user, mistakenly he/she enter the wrong answer my app will be crashed . if i make only one collection the problem is suppose my my application there are only 5 doctors and  100000 users  if users want to see all doctors list i need to cheak every person he is a doctors or not it will take time

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Firebase Custom Claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims). They are like roles assigned to the users. You need to use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) for assigned custom claims.
Now it entirely depends on your sign up flow that how and when are you going to assign the custom claims.

Coming to the part when you need to know if the current user is a Doctor or normal user, you can do so with the follow code in Android (Kotlin):

```
user.getIdToken(false).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<GetTokenResult>() {
  @Override
  public void onSuccess(GetTokenResult result) {
    boolean isDoctor = result.getClaims().get("doctor");
    if (isDoctor) {
      // Show doctor UI.
    } else {
      // Show regular user UI.
    }
  }
});
```

Then you can check if the logged in user is a doctor or no and then conditionally switch to relevant activities. Please let me know if you need help setting up Custom Claims in your sign up flow.

Comment: please tell me more can you give me an example I attached my code in my question

Comment: @AdarshDhakad please check the update code and try it, but before that please add custom claim to your user by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47497957/13130697)