# Set custom claims & role-based access for specific Google sign-in account

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

My firebase functions app makes use of Firebase & Google for authentication, checking for valid domains to grant access.

My concern is that a rogue employee can come along and destroy sensitive data. Thus, I wish to set custom claims for each account access the site from "admin" user of sorts.

There is already 2 questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47495678/how-to-create-firebase-authentication-claims) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60171473/firebase-how-to-set-custom-claim-from-the-console)) relating to this, being able to set claims in the Firebase console but this isn't yet a feature

**My question has 2 parts:**

1. How can I determine who my "admin" user is (I know the email, how do I set this user as the admin user)
2. How can this admin user set permissions for these accounts.

---

**Possible solution:**

The only solution I can think of is, upon for login, the account is saved in firestore e.g. `/portal-users/${email}/mode`

**Modes:**

- `none:` on initial registration, the "admin" user needs to accept this person as a valid portal user
- `user:` valid system user
- `revoked:` revoked email, cannot access system
- `admin:` well, admin I guess

**My implementation** using Firebase Functions & express follows this flow:

When **signing in** to `POST:/user/createSession`, I read the Firestore database and set custom claims using [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies#create_session_cookie) as a base:

```
// if you are wondering what happened to CSRF - I couldn't get that to work :(
const idToken = req.body.idToken.toString();
const expiresIn = 60 * 60 * 24 * 5 * 1000;

const auth = admin.auth();
auth.verifyIdToken(idToken).then(value => {
    console.log("Token verified")
    auth.setCustomUserClaims(value.uid, {mode: `insert mode here from firestore`}).then(value1 => {
        return auth.createSessionCookie(idToken, {expiresIn})
            .then((sessionCookie) => {
                // Set cookie policy for session cookie.
                const options = {maxAge: expiresIn, httpOnly: true, secure: true};
                res.cookie('session', sessionCookie, options);
                res.end(JSON.stringify({status: 'success'}));
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
                res.status(401).send('UNAUTHORIZED REQUEST!');
            });
    })
}).catch(reason => {
    console.error("Unable to verify token");
    console.error(reason);
    res.status(401).send('INVALID TOKEN!');
});
```

When requesting a auth `/any/route/with/private/data` route, the following check should be done (roughly) [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies#verify_session_cookie_and_check_permissions) way when validating a request:

```
admin
    .auth()
    .verifySessionCookie(sessionCookie, true)
    .then((decodedClaims) => {

        // Where the magic happens
        switch (decodedClaims.mode) {
            case "none": {
                // return to login screen with awaiting verification message
                break;
            }
            case "revoked": {
                // return to login screen with revoked permissions message
                break;
            }
            case "user": 
            case "admin":{
                // continue
                break;
            }
        }
        res.status(401).send('UNAUTHORIZED REQUEST!');
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        // Session cookie is unavailable or invalid. Force user to login.
        res.redirect('/login');
    });
```

To manage users' permissions, the admin user has a special page to set modes for each user on the system (which will eventually call `setCustomClaims()`, see above).

**Are there any issues or security problems I might face?** *(except the CSRF issue ofc)*

Answer (score 2):

A few things to be aware of. Custom claims are cached from the client, these can lead to valid tokens with expired information making false-positive modifications to your database. This is an inherit flaw with Firebase's Auth system being restful by design, to get around this you must revoke the users' Auth token when their custom claims have changed, there are several ways to handle this:

Propagate: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#propagate_custom_claims_to_the_client

Revoke: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions#revoke_refresh_tokens

The main issue is that the user will have to re-authenticate to update these changes and should only be used on extreme account-wide conditions, such as setting administrator privileges, etc. In contrast, Cloud Functions have the luxury of validating the user object and accessing auth directly for the updated claims but these are not reflected in Security Rules. (this would be my dream fix)

Since Firestore and Realtime do suffer from cached claims, it's often more viable to have these flags set on the user based on a database profile or 'role' table with their UID associated with the correct Role. doing multiple reads and writes is also helpful as these reads from within Firestore are Cached per request, up to a maximum of 10 unique documents.

Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents

Custom Claims currently is not a viable solution to Secure your database, only validation on Cloud Functions and user flags on the client. Using a combination of the above methods and Database roles is the best solution.

**Finding the user**

You can setup a onUser create trigger within cloud functions that checks the user's credentials and confirms it with your backend, ie: is the user auth'd from "google.com" and has a specific prefix, etc.

or if the user is already within your Firebase Auth collection, you can target them by UID or email - Email is not as secure compared to the user's UID, as this does not validate the auth provider.

One popular solution is a Cloud Function Extention that adds claims based on Firestore document changes
Source:

- Cloud Function Extention: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/experimental-extensions/blob/next/firestore-auth-claims/README.md
- Custom Cloud Function: https://github.com/digimbyte/FirebaseDevelopers/blob/master/Cloud%20Functions/Firestore%20Admin%20Manager.md

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I came up with this solution using custom claims in favour of reading (upon each request to the API/portal) as the reads would tally up after a while. Maybe security comes at a cost.

Comment: Thankfully reading is relatively cheap should you need to do so. it's the writes that are sufficiently more expensive which is when custom claims and roles would play more into your needs. making the read cost redundant in comparison

Comment: if you found my answer helpful, accepting it as an answer will help me out. if you have further questions, I am also available through comments.